# Turtle direction in turtle graphics?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

How can I tell a turtle to face a direction in turtle graphics?
I would like the turtle to turn and face a direction no matter its original position, how can I achieve this?

Comment: Well, there is always the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/turtle.html#turtle.setheading).

Answer (score 6):

I think `turtle.setheading()` AKA `seth()` is the function you're looking for, so if you want it to point North:

```
turtle.setheading(0)
```

or

```
turtle.setheading(90)
```

depending on whether you're in 'standard' or 'logo' mode.

As pointed out in the comments, you can find this info [here](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/turtle.html#turtle.setheading).

Answer (score 3):

This is what I used for my game:

```
#Functions
def go_up():
    head.direction="up"

def go_down():
    head.direction="down"

def go_left():
    head.direction="left"

def go_right():
    head.direction="right"


def move():
    if head.direction == "up":
        y = head.ycor()
        head.sety(y + 20)

    if head.direction == "down":
        y = head.ycor()
        head.sety(y - 20)

    if head.direction == "left":
        x = head.xcor()
        head.setx(x - 20)

    if head.direction == "right":
        x = head.xcor()
        head.setx(x + 20)

# Keyboard
win.listen()
win.onkeypress(go_up, "Up")
win.onkeypress(go_down, "Down")
win.onkeypress(go_left, "Left")
win.onkeypress(go_right, "Right")
```

Answer (score 1):

or if your planning on moving your turtle somewhere (x, y) and you want to point your turtle there first, you can use:

```
turtle.setheading(turtle.towards(x,y))
```

Comment: A couple more `setheading` patterns are available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53893727/6243352) (pointing towards another turtle, setting heading to the heading of another turtle).

Answer (score 1):

We can of course change the heading by `turtle.setheading()` / `turtle.seth()`

[image: turtle.setheading() docs]

I'm referring to this documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.setheading).

Comment: That answer was already given 5 years ago. Please, when answering to old questions, be sure to clarify how your answer is different, and even better, than existing answers. Besides, avoid [posting image of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: i wrote it myself tho

Comment: Hi. Not my point. I wasn't saying, not even thinking, that this was plagiarism or anything like that (that would have been a moderation problem, and I am not a moderator ; just a reviewer). I am sure you found the answer yourself. The point is that it is better to avoid posting redundant answer. It is about redundancy, not about merit.

Comment: Ok, but i refer to the docs, so we can review from there.

Answer (score 0):

The setheading command would be the way to do that.

```
turtle.setheading(<degrees/radians>)
```

is how you would use it. Without changing settings you will be in standard mode, so

```
turtle.setheading(0)
```

would face the turtle right,

```
turtle.setheading(90)
```

would face the turtle up,

```
turtle.setheading(180)
```

would face the turtle left,and

```
turtle.setheading(270)
```

would face the turtle down. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use:
`turtle.right(angle)`
or:
`turtle.left(angle)`.
Hope this helps!

Comment: This is relative to the current direction of the turtle.

Answer (score -1):

```
import turtle

angle = 50

turtle.tiltangle(angle)
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.