# Python turtle set direction of a turtle to another turtle

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I am using python 3.6 and turtle module. I have two turtles in another coordinates. how do i set the angle of turtle_1 to the direction of turtle_2?

Answer (score 3):

```
turtle_1.setheading(turtle_1.towards(turtle_2))
```

This is typically used if you want `turtle_1` to *chase* `turtle_2`.  The argument to `towards()` is flexible.  Besides another turtle, it can also be separate X and Y arguments, or a tuple coordinate pair. If you simply want `turtle_1` to point in the same direction as `turtle_2`:

```
turtle_1.setheading(turtle_2.heading())
```